# List Items empty when requested via Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the list of items from a sharepoint list via Microsoft Graph.
This is the method I'm using to get the application token:

```
    public async Task<string> GetAppToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var host = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
        var tokenUri = $"/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var requestedResource = "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default";//&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
        var request = $"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&scope={requestedResource}";
        var resultContent = "fail";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(host);
            var content = new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);

            var result = await client.PostAsync(tokenUri, content);
            resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(resultContent);
        return json.access_token;
    }
```

The access token returned contains these roles:

```
"Mail.ReadWrite",
"Device.ReadWrite.All",
"User.ReadWrite.All",
"Domain.ReadWrite.All",
"Calendars.Read",
"Group.Read.All",
"Directory.ReadWrite.All",
"MailboxSettings.Read",
"Contacts.ReadWrite",
"Group.ReadWrite.All",
"Notes.Read.All",
"User.Invite.All",
"Files.ReadWrite.All",
"Directory.Read.All",
"User.Read.All",
"Files.Read.All",
"Mail.Read",
"Calendars.ReadWrite",
"Mail.Send",
"MailboxSettings.ReadWrite",
"Contacts.Read",
"IdentityRiskEvent.Read.All",
"Member.Read.Hidden",
"Reports.Read.All",
"Notes.ReadWrite.All"
```

This is the code I'm using to make the request:

```
token = await GetAppToken();
var client = new HttpClient();
var queryString = new NameValueCollection();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
    = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

var uri = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";
var path = $"/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items";

var responseString = string.Empty;
try
{

    var response = await client.GetAsync($"{uri}{path}");
    if (response.Content != null)
    {
        responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex.ToString());
}
```

This url works to produce a response:

```
> var path =
> "/sites/[sitecol-guid],[site-guid]/lists/[list-guid]/items";
```

But the **values** collection is empty even though there are items in the list.
This is the actual json result:

```
{
    "@odata.context":"graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites(‌​'host, site-id')/lists('list-id')/items",
    "value":[]
}
```

I also tried this format for the list request:

```
var path = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint:/{list-path}"
```

This produced a valid json response detailing the list information but when I added on the /items segment, I got this error:

> "Resource not found for the segment 'items'.",

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Irwin, as you may have found we've revamped some site and list stuff as we the former went to GA and the latter was updated to a newer beta. Are you still seeing this issue now?

Comment: Saw the new content, applied the changes to get my API request to work again and still getting empty list. This is the result being returned:
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites('host, site-id')/lists('list-id')/items","value":[]}

Comment: Thanks for confirming Irwin. Can you tell me what scopes are present in the access token you're using to call Graph?

Comment: @Brad, using this as the requested resource in the token request: https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default

Comment: Ah it's app-only! Can you tell me what permissions you selected when you registered the app? Another way is to throw one of your tokens in https://jwt.io (if you want to play it safe you can wait for the token to expire first) and pull out the value for the "roles" claim

Comment: Hey @Brad, I've updated the question with the roles I requested for the app.

Comment: I'm also getting this issue with app only permissions.  I guess it's to do with the fact that the docs say we need Sites.Read.All or Sites.ReadWrite.All which aren't appearing in the application permissions, despite having selected "Read and write items and lists in all site collections" in the azure portal.

Comment: @Irwin Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: So I figured it out! My problem was that in addition to hitting 'save' in the azure console after adding the permissions you have to also click 'grant permissions' for your changes to take effect. I assumed that just saving the added permissions would automatically grant them. If this is clearly documented somewhere, I missed it, so if someone could point me to where this is documented that would help others in the future that may face this issue.


The other annoying thing about this is that there is no error returned when you are lacking the right permissions.

Comment: Returning an empty response in lieu of an error could be seen as graceful degradation, but it's also really hard for a developer to ascertain from the empty response for WHAT REASON the response is empty. If there were some sort of enhanced error code or some sort of tidbit pointing to lack of permissions that would be great.

Comment: I'm not going to give the bounty to myself (if that's even possible), so if someone wants to answer detailing the fact that you have to also grant permissions via a button in the azure portal in addition to saving the added permissions I'll award the bounty to you. Prerequisite is screenshots & detailed because I want it to serve as a reference for others who might face this issue.

Comment: Does [this](https://gautamdsheth.wordpress.com/2017/10/16/create-o365-groups-with-csom-c/) make sense, the initial steps ? The purpose of the blog was quite different though i agree :) Disclaimer, its my own blog

Comment: @GautamSheth That's actually pretty awesome! If you could post an answer with a link to that post that would be so great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something that's taken me a while to figure out from the docs.

Firstly, don't do anything programmatically until you've got it working on the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) - it is just a big waste of time.

Secondly, the beta version is not ready for your production system , so while it works well, don't rely on it, instead use v1.0 of the REST APIs.

If you know the ID of your site and list, then all URLs will start with one of the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/
```

***Note:*** In the examples below, I give the generic URL, then a real world one which worked for me - so you can see what the format looks like.

If you don't know the `listId`, lets say we're looking at lists in the root site, we can get them by using this URL in the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and click **Run Query**:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists
```

If you want to get all the columns in your list, paste this URL in the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and click **Run Query**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/columns
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/ff34268a-d9ff-49c0-99a9-75c6b2eee62e/columns
```

This returns something similar to:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('root')/lists('ff34268a-d9ff-49c0-99a9-75c6b2eee62e')/columns",
    "value": [
        {
            "columnGroup": "Custom Columns",
            "description": "",
            "displayName": "Title",
            "enforceUniqueValues": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "id": "fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247",
            "indexed": false,
            "name": "Title",
            "readOnly": false,
            "required": true,
            "text": {
                "allowMultipleLines": false,
                "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
                "linesForEditing": 0,
                "maxLength": 255
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

To get the value of what's in your list, use this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items?expand=fields
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/ff34268a-d9ff-49c0-99a9-75c6b2eee62e/items?expand=fields
```

Note the `expand=fields` query which actually adds the values of the items in your list

This returns something similar to:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('root')/lists('ff34268a-d9ff-49c0-99a9-75c6b2eee62e')/items",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"6a84a626-dae9-40eb-9c6d-899c6a05ffa8,3\"",
            "createdDateTime": "2017-01-03T11:11:42Z",
            "eTag": "\"6a84a626-dae9-40eb-9c6d-899c6a05ffa8,3\"",
            "id": "1",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-01-10T18:24:58Z",
            "webUrl": "https://myexample.sharepoint.com/Lists/Some%20Contacts/1_.000",
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    ...
                }
            },
            "parentReference": {},
            "contentType": {
                "id": "0x010062202D579C40994CA18FDBA6760B9545"
            },
            "fields@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('root')/lists('ff34268a-d9ff-49c0-99a9-75c6b2eee62e')/items('1')/fields/$entity",
            "fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "\"6a84a626-dae9-40eb-9c6d-899c6a05ffa8,3\"",
                "Title": "Dr",
                "First_x0020_Name": "David",
                "Surname": "Simpson",
                "Location": "Nottingham",
                "First_x0020_Created": "2017-01-03T08:00:00Z",
                "Age@odata.type": "#Single",
                "Age": 25,
                "id": "1",
                "ContentType": "Item",
                "Modified": "2017-01-10T18:24:58Z",
                "Created": "2017-01-03T11:11:42Z",
                "AuthorLookupId": "11",
                "EditorLookupId": "11",
                "_UIVersionString": "1.0",
                "Attachments": false,
                "Edit": "",
                "LinkTitleNoMenu": "Dr",
                "LinkTitle": "Dr",
                "ItemChildCount": "0",
                "FolderChildCount": "0",
                "_ComplianceFlags": "",
                "_ComplianceTag": "",
                "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime": "",
                "_ComplianceTagUserId": ""
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Though I'm using v1.0 of the graph, the beta works just the same.

In my actual app, I'm using `offline_access Sites.ReadWrite.All` as the scope for the OAuth dance. The former allows for token refresh; the latter for access to SharePoint Online in the Microsoft Graph.

Your authorize URL should look something like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
    ?client_id=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX
    &response_type=code
    &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%example.ngrok.io%2Foauth2%2Fcallback
    &response_mode=query
    &scope=offline_access+openid+Sites.ReadWrite.All
    &prompt=consent
```

---

**An aside:** Make sure you are using the Microsoft Graph API (at https://graph.microsoft.com/) rather than the Azure AD Graph API (at https://graph.windows.net/). If you put the wrong scope in your OAuth dance, [bad things will happen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/14/the-difference-between-the-tokens-used-by-microsoft-graph-and-azure-ad-graph/).

One good thing about using the Microsoft Graph API is that you don't have to bother adding any permissions in the Azure portal beforehand, because you can just add the permissions into the OAuth scope and reauth. This is much easier.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you granted admin consent. Here is an example of it.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant ID}/adminconsent?client_id={client id}&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments, you missed an important step which was to `Grant Permissions` which is basically does the admin consent.

This consent is needed for app only permissions which always require admin consent. If the app has delegated permissions, then by `Grant permissions` you can effectively give consent on behalf of all users and once done, it will suppress the prompt for users>

As mentioned in this blog (disclaimer my own blog) - [Consume the Graph API and create O365 groups/modern team sites with CSOM C#](https://gautamdsheth.wordpress.com/2017/10/16/create-o365-groups-with-csom-c/), we need to `Grant permissions` once we have given and saved permissions necessary to the app.

Reference - [Configure user consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent)